# What is the fastest way to validate (and report errors!) on a huge .ndjson file?

Tags: json, file-io, bigdata

I have a 42 GB file where each line is supposed to be a JSON object. I have reason to believe that somewhere in this file, there is a syntax error.

What would be the fastest way to find the line(s) with errors?

Some constraints:

- The line has about 21 000 lines, so some of them are very (!!!) long
- I don't want to find just the first error; I want to find *all* lines with errors
- I want the output to show me, at least, the line number (or the line contents) of the offending lines
- I'm doing this on Windows or (preferably) Ubuntu (through WSL2)

This script took about 1 minute for the first 1000 lines (1.2 GB), and is currently running on the full file:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

i=$((0))
time (
  while read line; do
    i=$((i + 1))
    echo "$line" | jq > /dev/null || echo error on line $i &
  done < blob_cache_update-20200812T034630.ndjson

  wait
  echo processed $i rows
)
```

What can I do to make this faster?

(Yes, experimenting with other languages is an option, assuming both installing required tooling and implementing the checker is simple enough not to completely overshadow running the checker.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do, apparently, is to switch to Python.

This (single-threaded!) approach took 5 minutes on the same file:

```
#!/bin/env python

import json
import time

# FILE = 'blob_cache_update-sample.ndjson'
FILE = 'blob_cache_update-20200812T034630.ndjson'

start = time.perf_counter()
with open(FILE, 'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i % 1000 == 0:
            print(f'{i}: {time.perf_counter() - start} s')

        try:
            parsed = json.loads(line)
            assert "blob" in parsed
            assert "sha" in parsed
            assert "size" in parsed
        except:
            print(f'error on line {i}')

end = time.perf_counter()

print(f"it took {end-start} s")
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to change/comment out the assert ... in parsed since I had different json fields